# What are the best practices for working with different languages?

Tags: java, python, ruby, shell, node.js

I've just jumped into a new project that combines many components written in different languages (Python, Ruby, Java & Perl). The project is kind of a pipeline that process documents and can be run as a command line shell script. The pipeline/shell script passes contents from tool to the other then finally print an output into a file. During the process some tools do print files then these files are used as an input into other tools.

My job in this project is to bring it to the web. So my question is what is the proper/best practices way/architecture that should be followed in such a project where you have many components writing in different languages?
And is Node.js the best tool/language that can combine components as *LinkedIn* says: "[If you look at Node, the thing it’s best at doing is talking to other services.](http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node)"

Comment: you can set up a web server to call your existing shell script. Why do you need anything more than that? It's not really clear what your requirements are, what node.js has to do with anything, or really what you're asking for.

Comment: I've just edited my question and the title hope that clarify it a bit. Sorry if I'm not good at expressing my ideas :(

Comment: Ok, but again, why not just call your existing shell script from the web server? Won't that solve the problem in a minimum of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the *proper* answer could fill books...

That said, I would suggest to avoid the unholy mess of tiny modules talking to who knows who, by implementing some kind of service bus. If you can get that right, all the languages/subprojects will have to be compatible with the bus only, not with each and every one of the others. That way the complexity will drop from N factorial to 2xN.

Comment: that is assuming that all the components initially had to be compatible with all the others. The way I read the OP's question, the tools form a somewhat fixed pipeline where the output from each tool is passed to *one* other tool which understands it.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing you should be most wary about is **security**. If you are exposing some scripts to be executable through the web especially if it requires user input, you want to **validate** it thoroughly.

This is probably the single most important thing. The choice of frameworks or architecture would be secondary to security.

Comment: -1 for overlooking the obvious: `The choice of frameworks or architecture would be secondary to security.` wrong choice will lead to unmanageable code, and that will __definitely__ lead to insecure code...

Comment: being secondary does not mean it is not important. If you are to prioritize (something will always be first and by extension second), there are other factors which are not to be ignored. Code maintainability is one. One pro-efficiency is in the said frameworks is one. An expert will write better code than a novice in any framework. I have seen stackoverflow errors in Java, which does alot to prevent such errors but obviously does not guard against one's ineptitude. You can choose framework first, and secure it when someone's passwords end up in a hacker forum. It is a matter of priority.